# Swift struct assignment failure

Tags: swift, struct, append

This seems like it should be trivial and it's driving me batty. This is my struct declaration:

```
struct ThemePic: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let pic: String
}
```

and this is the function with a compile error:

```
func themeChange(newEmojis: [String]) -> [ThemePic] {

    var newTheme: [ThemePic]
    var whichEmoji: Int
            
    for x in 0..<newEmojis.count {
        whichEmoji = Int.random(in: 0..<newEmojis.count)
        newTheme += (x, newEmojis[whichEmoji])
    }
    return newTheme
}
```

Whether I use += or append I get pretty much the same responses:

1. Operator function '+=' requires the types 'ContentView.themePic' and '(Int, String).Element' be equivalent
2. Type '(Int, String)' cannot conform to 'Sequence'

It's clearly saying that my types **do** match, so...?

Comment: Take some time and read the basics. It is Swift naming convention to name your structures starting with an uppercase letter `CamelCase` and your functions/methods with a lowercase letter `camelCase`

Comment: Fair enough, name changed. Do you have any advice on the problem?

Comment: append a new instance of `ThemePic` instead of using `+=`. `newTheme.append(.init(id: x, pic: newEmojis[.random(in: newEmojis.indices)]))` or simply iterate `newEmojis.indices` and use random element `newTheme.append(.init(id: x, pic: newEmojis.randomElement()!))`

Comment: I also don't understand why you are using the collection index `x` and assigning a random element

Comment: `themePic` is a struct, and `(x, newEmojis[whichEmoji])` is a tuple. That's why, there is nothing to do with `Identifiable`.

Comment: Ooooooh, that explains it. Thank you Leo and Larme so much for your time! I'm just getting started in Swift and I come from a much more procedural language background...as you may have guessed...

Comment: Just a follow-up to the naming convention comment from https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus. I am a long-time procedural programmer (old school stuff, like Fortran, Basic, yes even COBOL...) and just starting with Swift. https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/ says "Names of types and protocols are UpperCamelCase. Everything else is lowerCamelCase." So in this case I'm not defining a new type, but a struct. That's why I thought it should be named the way it was. Please help me understand so I develop better coding habits.

Answer (score 2):

The `+` (or `+=`) operator can be used to append another array to an array. It is *not* used to add an element to an array, like you are trying to do here. Use the `append` method instead.

Your array is also not an array of tuples, so you cannot add tuples such as `(x, newEmojis[whichEmoji])` into it. It is an array of `ThemePic`s. You should create a `ThemePic` instance using its initialiser.

```
var newTheme: [ThemePic] = [] // remember to initialise the array!
var whichEmoji: Int

for x in 0..<newEmojis.count {
    whichEmoji = Int.random(in: 0..<newEmojis.count)
    newTheme.append(ThemePic(id: x, pic: newEmojis[whichEmoji]))
}
return newTheme
```

This can be done in a much shorter way using `map`:

```
(0..<newEmojis.count).map { ThemePic(id: $0, pic: newEmojis.randomElement()!) }
```

It seems like you are trying to *shuffle* the `newEmojis` and turn them into `ThemePic`s. If that is the case, then please note that your current approach might produce `ThemePic`s with duplicate `pic`s, as `Int.random` could return the same thing in two iterations. If that is undesirable, you can do something like:

```
newEmojis.shuffled().enumerated().map(ThemePic.init)
```

Comment: why not simply `newEmojis.shuffled().enumerated().map(ThemePic.init)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Wow. I didn't know that'd work!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because the types you are trying to combine actually *don't* match. Specifically:

1. `newTheme` is an `Array` of `themePic` values
2. The value you are trying to append to the array is not a `themePic` but a tuple: `(Int, String)`

There is no automatic conversion between `(Int, String)` and a `themePic`, so you need to construct a `themePic` out of the values you have in order to append:

```swift
newTheme.append(themePic(id: x, pic: newEmojis[whichEmoji]))
```

---

Additional notes:

1. Idiomatic Swift naming guidelines would have the name of the type be capitalized: `themePic` → `ThemePic`
2. Similarly with your function name, which should be camelCased: `ThemeChange` → `themeChange`
3. Once you fix the above error, you'll also need to appropriately initialize `newTheme` before you can append to it:

   ```
   var newTheme: [ThemePic] = []

   // OR

   var newTheme = [ThemePic]()
   ```

Combining these together:

```swift
struct ThemePic: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let pic: String
}

func themeChange(newEmojis: [String]) -> [ThemePic] {
    var newTheme = [ThemePic]()
    var whichEmoji: Int
            
    for x in 0..<newEmojis.count {
        whichEmoji = Int.random(in: 0..<newEmojis.count)
        newTheme.append(ThemePic(id: x, pic: newEmojis[whichEmoji]))
    }
    return newTheme
}
```

[@Sweeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70837472/169394) also covers how you might want to avoid manually looping altogether by using `Sequence` methods directly.